# Random ConcurrentModificationException in Tomcat application

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, siteminder

We have a java application deployed in Tomcat 7.0.54. In front of tomcat there is an Apache 2.4.10 with SiteMinder module as reverse proxy. Tomcat is running under Sun jdk 1.8.0-45-64bit.

There is a floating bug when request to random resource (icon or js scripts or css) of application fails with

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    java.util.PriorityQueue$Itr.next(PriorityQueue.java:535)
    java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
    com.our.groupid.entity.auth.User.getAllPermissionsAsListOfStrings(User.java:129)
    com.our.groupid.app.auth.SiteMinderSessionUserDetails.&lt;init&gt;(SiteMinderSessionUserDetails.java:17)
    com.our.groupid.app.auth.SiteMinderAuthenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(SiteMinderAuthenticationDetailsSource.java:61)
    com.our.groupid.app.auth.SiteMinderAuthenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(SiteMinderAuthenticationDetailsSource.java:13)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:178)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

What even worse it couldn't be reproduced in standalone Tomcat. I suppose that something is wrong with sessions\requests between Apache and Tomcat but couldn't find anything suspicious in log.

Does anyone have any idea about root cause of such behavior?

Comment: Do you know what `ConcurrentModificationException` is?

Comment: Yep. When more than one process\thread modifying the same part of data. But it doesn't looks like application error. As I mentioned before in standalone Tomcat all works great.

Comment: False. Threads/processes have nothing to do with `ConcurrentModificationException` (well, they might, but you can achieve it quite easily in a single thread). Do a search here and you'll find plenty of posts where it's explained (as well as plenty of posts where people share your misunderstanding).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found it. 
Apache was operating with `mod_proxy_http` and does some mess with headers. 
Switch to `mod_proxy_ajp` solves my issue. So `ConcurrentModificationException` was only symptom.